# Check if data is loaded in grid when data is changeable in Testcomplete

Tags: testing, testcomplete

I want to check if data is loaded in grid. Now I use Property Checkpoint->Content Text, but my data is invariable.If my data is changeable, how I can check data is loaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the property of the grid control that is telling how many items the grid contains. This will make you be able to validate that there are the correct number of items or at least one record exists in the grid.

Also, you can create a script function that will read data from the grid control using its native methods and properties and validate data within this function as you need.